# My Qt app never open full screen and the maximized button is disable

Tags: qt

My app  never open full windows and can't maximize it, the button is disable.

The values of my `QMainWindow`, btw I never tocuh this values but in my mac it works fine. now I change computers, to a Windows and I have this problems

```
sizePolicy
    Horizontal Policy: Preferred
    Vertical Policy: Prefered
minimumSize
    Width: 0
    Height: 800
maximumSize
    Width: 16777215
    Height: 0
```

Comment: So you're aware, they are spelled "minimum" and "maximum".

Comment: Please edit your question  to provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem.